# Variável Calendar atualiza a outra quando a segunda é atualizada?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Olá, estive mexendo com a classe GregorianCalendar e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Tinha que percorrer de um ponto no calendário até o outro, depois setar o primeiro ponto como o segundo, logo em seguida, "resetar" o segundo campo e percorrer de volta. basicamente o seguinte:

```
GregorianCalendar gc1=new GregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar gc2=new GregorianCalendar();
gc1.setTime(meuTempo1);
gc2.setTime(meuTempo2);
while(!gc2.equals(variavel)){//eu tinha que voltar a gc2 até um determinado ponto
//que não necessariamente é igual a gc1.
//percorre o tempo, tirando o tanto de gc2
}
gc1=gc2;//aqui está o problema
gc2.setTime(meuTempo2);
```

Basicamente, percorri de volta um determinado, dei um `gc1=gc2`e setei novamente o gc2 como ele era antes. O problema, é que quando eu dava o `gc2.setTime(meuTempo2);` a variável gc1 também recebia aquele parâmetro, ou seja, os atributos do gc1 também mudaram, como se eu tivesse colocado uma segunda linha `gc1.setTime(meuTempo2);`.

Foi fácil resolver isso, bastou substituir `gc1=gc2` por `gc1.setTime(gc2.getTime());` mas eu fiquei na dúvida, se eu instanciei uma variável nova, ela não deveria pegar os atributos e depois ficar independente da segunda? Se não, em quais casos isso pode acontecer? E se possível, como tratar esse problema?

Comment: Não tinha lido o final da pergunta. O que acontece é que você está passando a referencia do objeto(endereço de memória), e não seu valor. Outra coisa, para comparar datas e tempo, se você estiver usando JDK8, é recomendável que utilize as classes do pacote java.time, essas classes antigas tem vários problemas quanto a comparação.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu perguntei, como contornar isso em outras classes?usando os setters todos? nesse caso ainda tem o `setTime`, mas tenho classes que tem mais de 30 atributos, vou usando `setAtributo(getAtributo())` em todos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazer `gc1=gc2` não copia os valores dos atributos de `gc2` para `gc1`. Ao fazer isso, você está copiando a referência de `gc2` para `gc1`. Em um nível mais baixo, significa que `gc1` e `gc2` apontam agora para o mesmo endereço de memória aonde está o objeto do tipo `GregorianCalendar`. Portanto, qualquer alteração no atributo que seja feita por meio do `gc1` e do `gc2` está afetando o mesmo objeto.

No caso do `GregorianCalendar`, você pode copiar os valores dos atributos utilizando o método [clone](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar.clone%28%29). Algo dessa maneira:

```
gc1 = (GregorianCalendar)gc2.clone();
```

Note que o código acima está atribuindo um novo objeto `GregorianCalendar` para `gc1` com os valores clonados de `gc2`.

Comment: isso funciona para outras classes também? Digamos, uma entidade que eu mesmo criei para o banco de dados por exemplo

Comment: @ThomasBrazPinto, não. Você precisa implementar o seu método clone e dizer como você quer clonar. Geralmente, o que faço é usar reflection para facilitar essa clonagem. Portanto, não faço atributo por atributo, uso reflection para fazer um loop em meus atributos, copiando os valores. Entretanto, tem uma série de questoes, como: e se o seu objeto tiver uma Collection, você vai clonar a Collection tb? Por isso, o Clone é feito caso-a-caso.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: É preciso implementar a interface Cloneable para usar o método Clone, ver aqui: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Comment: fiquei pensando aqui, e fiquei com outra dúvida, se eu deixasse do jeito inicial, e fizesse a alteração na variável `gc1` a alteração seria "vista" na `gc2` também?

Comment: @ThomasBrazPinto, creio que você deva mudar a maneira de pensar. Conceitos de ponteiro são fundamentais para que você entenda referência no Java (Java usa ponteiro, mas ele abstrai boa parte do desenvolvedor). Ao fazer gc1=gc2, você está fazendo com que gc1 aponte para o mesmo endereço de memória de gc2.  Esse endereço de memória que gc1 e gc2 referenciam, contém o objeto propriamente dito, nesse caso uma instância de GregoriaCalendar. Por isso, não é uma questão de "ver" a alteração, a questão é que ambas as duas variáveis apontam para o mesmo objeto.